# Unable to create a Cloud Composer environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I try to create a Composer environment, I get an error saying http error status code 400, bad request.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud composer needs a VPC network to run on. Either you may have deleted the default network or you don't have a subnet in the region where you want your Composer environment, in case you are using a custom network. Please refer this for network configuration [Setting up a Composer environment](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#creating_a_new_environment).

For creating a custom network you can refer[2](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#create-custom-network).